# Peewee: CompoundSelectQuery must be bound to database to call exists()

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I have the model classes `A` and `B` representing two tables with different columns, but both containing a `code`-column. I now want to check whether a given code-`candidate` does not already exist in one of these tables.

In peewee, I had in mind to select the `code`-column of `A` and `B`, UNION both to `AB` and run an existence check within `AB`:

```
candidate = 'randomCode'
AB = A.select(A.code) | B.select(B.code)
if not AB.select().where(AB.c.code == candidate).exists():
    print('candidate does not exist')
```

This results in the error `peewee.InterfaceError: Query must be bound to a database in order to call "exists"`. According to the peewee-docs, `exists()` expects a database, but even with it as parameter, the error seems to propagate to an underlying function: `peewee.InterfaceError: Query must be bound to a database in order to call "scalar"`.

I am even more confused, since the existence check for one table works like a charm, without a database as explicit parameter:

```
candidate = 'randomCode'
if not A.select().where(A.code == candidate).exists():
    print('candidate does not exist')
```

For now, I solved the issue by running two seperate existence-checks for `A` and `B`, anding the results. Still, I am curious to know what exactly I am doing wrong and how this problem could be solved for a CompoundSelectQuery, which would be much neater, in my opinion.

Comment: Are you using the lower-level query builder stuff like `Table`? Or are `A` and `B` model classes?

Comment: @coleifer Model Classes

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something wrong. It works fine for me:

```
from peewee import *                                                                                                 

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class A(Base):
    a = TextField()

class B(Base):
    b = TextField()

db.create_tables([A, B])

qa = A.select()
qb = B.select()
qu = qa | qb
print(qu.exists())

A.create(a='a')

print(qu.exists())
```